# DependencyProperty Binding Does Not Update To Collection CurrentItem

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, binding

I am trying to bind a dependency property to a collection's current selection and for reasons I can't seem to grasp, the binding does not update when the collection changes.

In the example below, I show two example. One is updating correctly (on the textblock/run), and the other only displays the initial element and doesn't change when the data grid selection changes.

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Path=List}" x:Key="myViewModel"/>
        <my:UpdateNotWorking MyObjModel="{Binding Source={StaticResource myViewModel}, Path=CurrentItem}" x:Key="updateNotWorking" />
    </Grid.Resources>

    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myViewModel}}" Name="mylistbox"/>
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF50CEFF" FontSize="24" TextAlignment="Center" Height="75">
            <Run Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource myViewModel}, Path=text}" Foreground="#FF00E200" />
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource updateNotWorking}, Path=MyObjModel.text}" Height="22"/>

</Grid>
```

My dependency property in this example is "MyObjModel" on the "UpdateNotWorking" dependency object which is instantiated from the xaml code.

I would appreciate any information as to why my property is not updating correctly.

[Example Project](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=100AF80ACE896AA0!6327&authkey=!AGK5kaxS6cpFtEg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paste this XAML into your MainWindow.

```
  <Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
      <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Path=List}" x:Key="myViewModel" />
      <my:UpdateNotWorking x:Key="updateNotWorking" />
    </Grid.Resources>

    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myViewModel}}" Name="mylistbox"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Source={StaticResource updateNotWorking}, Path=MyObjModel, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF50CEFF" FontSize="24" TextAlignment="Center"
               Height="75">
      <Run Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource myViewModel}, Path=text}" Foreground="#FF00E200" />
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource updateNotWorking}, Path=MyObjModel.text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             Height="22" />

  </Grid>
```

What it is now doing is setting `updateNotWorking`'s `MyObjModel` property based on the DataGrid's `SelectedValue`, with `UpdatePropertyTrigger` set to `PropertyChanged` to see the changes immediately.  No longer do we need to define `updateNotWorking`'s property through the List's CurrentItem because it is not going to change just by selecting it with a DataGrid. You *can* keep it set, but it is not required as we are doing all the manual labor with the `DataGrid SelectedValue`.

Comment: This works, but I still don't understand why the previous code isn't working. Am I not binded to the collection view's current item? Why doesn't it change?

Comment: Because CurrentItem is read-only, and it isn't a dependency property (so it cannot be bound to), and finally it does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged so it is not useful for any sort of UI bindings. On the other hand, DataGrid's SelectedValue is a dependency property and enjoys all of the requirements to make UI bindings work well.  So we've essentially just "reversed" what you were doing, where your route was passively waiting for the value to change [to no avail] while this is actively changing the value.

Comment: That makes it much clearer. Thank you so much for your explanation!